# Scalac cannot infer inductively built path-dependent type

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

I'm working on a port of `servant-server` to Scala. The idea is to use typeclass resolution to inductively build functions that can handle requests. I'm running into some weird inference issues I can't quite figure out.

```
object Servant {                                                                     

  class :>[Path, A]                                                                  

  trait HasServer[A] {                                                               
    type ServerT                                                                     

    def route(a: ServerT): String                                                    
  }                                                                                  

  implicit val unitServer = new HasServer[Unit] {                                    
    type ServerT = String                                                            

    def route(str: ServerT): String = str                                            
  }                                                                                  

  implicit def subServer[A, Sub](implicit sub: HasServer[Sub]) = new HasServer[A :> Sub] {
    type ServerT = A => sub.ServerT                                                  

    def route(handler: ServerT): String = "handler"                                  
  } 

}
```

With the above, the following fails to compile:

```
val foo = implicitly[HasServer[Int :> Unit]]
implicitly[=:=[Int => String, foo.ServerT]]
```

The error is:

```
servant.scala:33: error: 
Cannot prove that Int => String =:= Main.$anon.Servant.foo.ServerT.
```

However, it *will* compile if I instantiate `HasServer[Int :> Unit]` directly, via:

```
  val foo = new HasServer[Int :> Unit] {                                             
    type ServerT = Int => unitServer.ServerT                                         

    def route(handler: ServerT): String = handler(10)                                
  }
```

How can I get this to compile? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is all in the definition of `implicitly` ...

```
def implicitly[T](implicit e: T) = e
```

`implicitly[T]` will only ever give you a value which is typed as `T`, never anything more precise. In the case above, that's `HasServer[Int :> Unit]` which, crucially, leaves the member type `ServerT` unconstrained.

This is commonly worked around by defining a per type class companion object `apply` method which preserves the desired refinement, eg.,

```
object HasServer {
  def apply[T](implicit hs: HasServer[T]):
    HasServer[T] { type ServerT = hs.ServerT } = hs
}
```

the result type here is a little unwieldy, so it's also common to combine this with the "Aux" pattern,

```
object HasServer {
  type Aux[T, S] = HasServer[T] { type ServerT = S }
  def apply[T](implicit hs: HasServer[T]): Aux[T, hs.ServerT] = hs
}
```

which will probably come in handy elsewhere in any case.

We can see the difference this makes to the inferred types on the REPL,

```
scala> implicitly[HasServer[Int :> Unit]]
res0: Servant.HasServer[Servant.:>[Int,Unit]] = ...

scala> HasServer[Int :> Unit]
res1: Servant.HasServer[Servant.:>[Int,Unit]]{type ServerT = Int => String} = ...
```

This refinement will be inferred as the type of a val definition, so now you'll get the desired result,

```
scala> val foo = HasServer[Int :> Unit]
foo: Servant.HasServer[Servant.:>[Int,Unit]]{type ServerT = Int => String} = ...

scala> implicitly[=:=[Int => String, foo.ServerT]]
res2: =:=[Int => String,foo.ServerT] = <function1>
```

There are a number of ways that the definition of `implicitly` could be improved to avoid this problem. The following is the most straightforward for reference types,

```
def implicitly[T <: AnyRef](implicit t: T): t.type = t
```

and if [literal types](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/5310) are enabled we could removed the `<: AnyRef` bound and define it for all types,

```
def implicitly[T](implicit t: T): t.type = t
```

shapeless provides a `the[T]` operator which behaves similarly to the latter via a macro.

Comment: It's funny, I've used Aux trick for 2 years now and never relied on `implicitly` and just became aware that implicitly never returns a more precise type than what you ask :) ... one day, one knowledge ;)